# Navigation width to be increased (slowly) on mouseover

Tags: javascript, navigation

I am new to javascript. I have been asked to do something like the navigation show on http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxys3/feature.html#smartstay

I have a class called .container which includes many subclasses. I am require to increase the width of the .menu on mouseover. Currently, during mouseover event, 2 element are affected. Is it possible to change the code so that only the current mouseover element would be affected?

I had heard that tween is able to do the job. Currently using tween.js now.

Below is my code:

```
        $('.menu').mouseover(function(){
            var i=0;

            //case sensitive
            $('.menu').width('50px');
            tweenTA2 = new Tween(new Object(),'xyz',Tween.regularEaseOut,0,100,1);
            var myelem = $(this);

            tweenTA2.onMotionChanged = function(event){ 
                $(this).text('here');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            i= i+1;
                            if (i < 100)
                            {

                                myelem.width(i);
                                myelem.css("background-color", "yellow");
                            }


                        },100);
            };
            tweenTA2.onMotionStarted = function(event){ 
                        $('.menu').width('50px');
            };
            //tweenTA2.onMotionResumed = function(event){
            //  $('.menu').width('50px');
            //};    
            tweenTA2.start();       


        });
```

I am not sure about tween either (e.g. start, end. duration)

Can you assist in reproducing the effect on the site I posted?

Comment: I would look at `jquery animation width` plus perhaps  `easing jquery bounce`

Comment: Hi mplugjan are you refering to JQuery .animate()? It doesn't work, once i mouseover from one header to another, 2 header had an increase in width. I need only one header to increase its width at a time. Thanks you for ur help~

Comment: Of course it works, you need to animate the width back when you leave the element or when you enter the next element

Comment: sorry i am quite new to this could you perhaps give an example on "enter the next element" part?

Thanks you so much!~

Comment: I meant on focus of the next element or blur of the current

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support older browsers, then I would suggest forgetting about JavaScript completely and using CSS3 transitions to accomplish this without any external libraries.

Something like

```
#menu {
    width:100px;
    transition:width 1s ease-in-out;
    }

#menu:hover {
    width:300px;
    transition:width 1s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Once you've added vendor prefixes this will work on most modern browers, and for older ones will gracefully degrade to immediately displaying the full width on hover.

Comment: Hi Graham thank you so much for ur reply. However, since i had used javascript to compute the width the width of ".menu" which depend on the amount of header the navigation had. For example if the Navigation includes  header1, header2, header3, if header 1 had been mouseover I would require header1 width to be 28% of the .container while (100%-28%)/2[divide by 2 since there is only 2 header left]. my html look like this:   
<div class="container">
     <div class="menu"></div>
     <div class= "menu"></div>
</div>